# Unsetting bash function having name of executable prevents further use of executable

Tags: macos, bash, libreoffice, openoffice

I created a function to enable me to run libreoffice from the command line (under MacOS):

`libreoffice () { open -a libreoffice "$@"; }`

Wanting access to the base functionality of libreoffice, I unset that function:

`unset -f libreoffice`

Now, when I invoke libreoffice I get back:

`-bash: libreoffice: command not found`

How can I recover use of libreoffice, and what would have been a better way to remove/unset the function?

Comment: You are correct @KamilMaciorowski. (Apologies for the delay in my response.) Original function had the same name as the executable, 'libreoffice'.

Comment: "I created a function to enable me to run libreoffice from the command line" – Does "to enable" imply that "running libreoffice from the command line" was "disabled"? So it didn't work, right? Now you unset the function and again it doesn't work. You're back where you started, right? Did you expect to be in any other place (i.e. setup)? Frankly I don't know if `open -a` uses `$PATH` in macOS, but `command not found` from Bash is usually because the given command is not in `$PATH`. What is the output of `echo "$PATH"`? In what directory is your `libreoffice` executable?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, the reason for creating the function is to enable running libreoffice from the command line (I refuse to give up on my linux behaviors) while using MacOS. MacOS doesn't know what to do wtih `libreoffice <my_fav_file.odt>` out of the box; it seems to want to force people to use their GUI. (There may be better solutions, but this is what I found.)

Comment: It really looks like `$PATH` doesn't include the directory where your `libreoffice` executable is. I know little about macOS and I cannot tell if altering `$PATH` is the best solution. Again: what is the output of `echo "$PATH"`? In what directory is your `libreoffice` executable?